# How to duplicate object in JS where duplicate changes if you change original

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am making a planner/calendar website that is going to have a repeat function.

```
var chain = _.chain(state.items).filter({'id': 1}).head().value();
console.log(chain);
```

Here i filter one object, how do i duplicate `chain` that when i change the original the duplicate also changes and the other way around?

Comment: Use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to avoid object duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables that are assigned a non-primitive value are given a reference to that value. That reference points to the object’s location in memory. The variables don’t actually contain the value. This is why the original value changing when you're changing the duplicate.

This can be solved by using JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify()

Create a new function in the `methods` section

```
cloneObject:function(obj){
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Now you can call this method to make a copy of any object, like

```
var items = this.cloneObject(state.items); // this will create a clone of the object
var chain = _.chain(items).filter({'id': 1}).head().value();
```

Here the filter won't effect the `state.items` since we made a clone of this data.

If you're already using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) JS library, you can use the `cloneDeep()` method to make the copy

> Eg:

```
var items = _.cloneDeep(state.items);
var chain = _.chain(items).filter({'id': 1}).head().value();
console.log(chain);
```